# MIME Header in message when sending e-mail with Python

Tags: python, mime, email

So I am trying to send out an email using this template and using a log file as the body, the email gets sent fine. However, it has this really ugly header in the body of the message (As seen below)

```
From nobody Thu Mar 17 14:13:14 2011
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Is there anyway to make it so the message does not include the header above? Thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
import time
import datetime
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
today = datetime.date.today()
textfile = "/home/user/Public/stereo-restart-log"
FROM = "my-username"
TO = ["recipients"]

SUBJECT = "Stereo log: %s" % today
fp = open(textfile, 'rb')
TEXT = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()
message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, TO, SUBJECT, TEXT)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login('my-username','mypass')
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.close()
```

Comment: Okay, amuse me. *Why* can those headers not be included?

Comment: I am assuming you're asking why I don't want them there? Because they are ugly and annoying and no one needs to know any of that information

Comment: There's really 2 issues here.  The first line is gibberish, not an header, and should not be included in your output.  The other three lines, however, are valid and *should* be included in your output, assuming that it actually has any MIME content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MIMEText you have already created the message object. You just need to add the proper headers to it:

```
FROM = "my-username"
TO = ["recipients"]
SUBJECT = "Stereo log: %s" % today
fp = open(textfile, 'rb')
TEXT = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()
TEXT['From'] = FROM
TEXT['To'] = ",".join(TO)
TEXT['Subject'] = SUBJECT
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login('my-username','mypass')
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, TEXT.as_string)
server.close()
```

Note that you can must convert the TO list to string before adding as header, because the square brackets are not allowed in the To/From headers.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I took the list out to paste it here. Thanks the TEXT.as_string worked.

Comment: TEXT.as_string should be TEXT.as_string()